# Who should be a socket server and who should be a client in the case of `adb forward` and `usbmuxd`

Tags: android, ios, sockets, mobile

I'm trying to create a server-client connection between a desktop computer and many mobile devices via USB.

To me, it makes sense to create one socket server on the desktop side to listen to a specific port for connections, while letting multiple mobile devices connect to this port. However, [the info I found on usbmuxd](https://medium.com/@jon.gabilondo.angulo_7635/understanding-usbmux-and-the-ios-lockdown-service-7f2a1dfd07ae) says the mobile device is supposed to be the socket server instead:

```
In practice it is possible to **create a socket server in a free port from an iOS** App and to connect to it from the host machine sending the following command via the /var/run/usbmuxd Unix socket (File Descriptor):

<?xml version=”1 .0" encoding=”UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC “-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN” “http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList1.0.dtd”>
<plist version=”1.0">
<dict>
<key>ClientVersionString</key>
<string>usbmuxd-423.206.4</string>
<key>DeviceID</key>
<integer>4</integer>
<key>MessageType</key>
<string>Connect</string>
<key>PortNumber</key>
<integer>My port</integer>  <--- The port number (with endian transform htonl)
<key>ProgName</key>
<string>usbmuxd</string>
</dict> 
</plist>
```

With Android, it seems that `adb forward tcp:<port1> tcp:<port2>` does similar by forwarding desktop-host port but the host is essentially a socket client. To my understanding, then the host must know all the ports on arbitrary devices and the devices must make sure those ports are unique, making it hard to automate the handshaking process with multiple devices.

Is this by design? Is it impossible to invert the server-client relationship between desktop and mobile this way?

Or am I wrong about the whole thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both `adb forward` and `usbmuxd` (usually via `iproxy`) forward a TCP port on your PC to your mobile device. That means your PC is a client, and your mobile device acts as a TCP server.

Normally you start a well-known application on your mobile device, which always exposes the same port (say, 2000). You can connect to your app running on your device by doing  `adb forward tcp:3000 tcp:2000` or `iproxy 3000 2000`. You can then connect to port 2000 *on your device* by connecting to port 3000 *on your PC*.

If you have multiple devices, you can use different ports *on your PC*, and have them forward to the same port *on the device*. For example, you could use `adb forward -s device_1 tcp:3001 tcp:2000` and `adb forward -s tdevice_2 tcp:3002 tcp:2000`. Connecting to port 3001 *on your PC* would end up connecting to port 2000 *on device 1*, and port 3002 *on your PC* would map to port 2000 *on device 2*.